# Code Textarea in Javascript

Tags: javascript, textarea, richtextbox

I want something like a rich-text editor for my website that is for code (should be able to do things like syntax highlight, indent on the fly, show line numbers).

I like Mozilla Bespin, but it is quite unstable right now, and has a little bit TOO much functionality for me.

Anything else out there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just two days ago I learned of [CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net/).
What are the odds?

Comment: was juuust about to link that one :P

Answer (score 0):

Something like [markItUp](http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/home/)?